# TreeView Grouping

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, treeview

My goal is to create a tree view from a single collection, but group it based on specific properties, as you see below:

```
(Alphabetical View)
      Test Machine 1
    > Test Machine 2
        |_ Test Device 1
        |_ Test Device 2
    > Test Machine 3
        |_ Test Device 3
        |_ Test Device 4
      Test Machine 4

(Location View)
    > Chicago
        |_ Test Machine 1
        |_ Test Machine 4       
    > Green Bay
        |_ Test Machine 3
        |_ Test Device 3
        |_ Test Device 4
    > Louisville
        |_ Test Machine 2
            |_ Test Device 1
        |_ Test Device 2

(Status View)
    > Connected
        |_ Test Machine 1
        |_ Test Machine 2
            |_ Test Device 1
            |_ Test Device 2
    > Disconnected
        |_ Test Machine 3
            |_ Test Device 3
            |_ Test Device 4

    > Unknown
        |_ Test Machine 4

(Device Type View)
    > Type A
        |_ Test Device 1
        |_ Test Device 3
    > Type B        
        |_ Test Device 2
        |_ Test Device 4
```

Below a basic breakdown of my classes and some sample data for the examples above:

```
public class Machine
{
    public string MachineName { get; set;}
    public string Location { get; set;} 
    public IList<Device> Devices { get; set;}
    public Status Status { get; set;}
}

public class Device
{
    public string DeviceName { get; set;}
    public string DeviceType { get; set;}
}

public enum Status
{
    Unknown,
    Disconnected,
    Connected
}

public IList<Machine> Machines
{
    get 
    {
        return new IList<Machine>()
        {
            new Machine { MachineName = "Test Machine 1", Location = "Chicago", Status = Status.Connected, Devices = new List<Device>() },
            new Machine { MachineName = "Test Machine 2", Location = "Louisville", Status = Status.Connected, Devices = new List<Device>
                                                                                                                            {
                                                                                                                                new Device { DeviceName = "Test Device 1", DeviceType = "Type A"},
                                                                                                                                new Device { DeviceName = "Test Device 2", DeviceType = "Type B"},
                                                                                                                            }},
            new Machine { MachineName = "Test Machine 3", Location = "Green Bay", Status = Status.Disconnected, Devices = new List<Device>
                                                                                                                            {
                                                                                                                                new Device { DeviceName = "Test Device 3", DeviceType = "Type A"},
                                                                                                                                new Device { DeviceName = "Test Device 4", DeviceType = "Type B"},
                                                                                                                            } },
            new Machine { MachineName = "Test Machine 4", Location = "Chicago", Status = Status.Unknown, Devices = new List<Device>() }
        }
    }
}
```

Currently, I do this by creating a child ViewModel for each grouping of the TreeView in my primary ViewModel. Then, on a button press, I change the ViewModel bound to a ContentControl. The ContentControl is then able to use Implicit Templating to draw it specifically for that grouping.

Is there a way to do this with a CollectionViewSource and it's Grouping capabilities as listed [here](http://www.zagstudio.com/blog/365#.UtbWLYV-49h)? I think that would save me about 7 classes...

Comment: @elgonzo Upvote it if you think so because it'll get more visibility that way. My working solution can be seen here: https://github.com/killnine/MvvmTest. But it requires I have about 7 more classes.

Answer (score 1):

If your items are going to be large in number I bet your current solution is most suited because you can apply threading.

`CollectionViewSource` and `Grouping` will be agnostically GUI threaded and also would loose `Virtualization` of `ThreeView`.

As a developer I prefer to not reduce number of classes even if you are too may. :-)

Comment: Wow, that's an incredibly thoughtful and helpful comment. I didn't realize that about `Grouping` and threading. Also, WPF is awesome!

Comment: Yes WPF is awesome. :)